# How do I update my primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Ok, this is probably really simple, but I just can't figure it out. I have a primary key in a table that goes from 1-5,000. I need to manually update that id (for other table update purposes) so that it says 5,000-10,000. Can't I manually update this column? Please help!!! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON

UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = columnName + 5000

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName OFF
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should clarify. I need it to start with 5,000-10,000, in place of 1-5,000

Comment: SET columnName = columnName + 5001

then 
SET columnName = columnName -1 (otherwise you will get error about duplicate primary key). So you need to execute 2 UPDATE statements.